# Creating a blurred ios 7 notification drawer style background

Tags: ios, blur, sketch-app

I'm new to sketch 3 and I really want to create that blurry background you have over the icons when you pull it down. I've followed a tutorial for blur in Sketch 3 but I didn't achieve exactly what I wanted.

This is my result:
[image]

But I would like to achieve this:
[image]

My result makes the icons stand out, but I want them to be more blurry. How can I accomplish this?

thanks!

Sincerely,
Erik

Comment: There isn't much difference, I just need it a little more blurry

Comment: Oh, now I noticed the "Amount" setting..

Comment: Sketch has been growing in questions here. If you don't mind taking a screenshot of the setting and posting it as an Answer others might find it useful. I don't think many of our regulars use Sketch yet.

Comment: and it wouldn't hurt posting a link to the tutorial and pointing out where it started going wrong, if at all possible.

Answer (score 15):

For anyone interested, you can achieve this effect by drawing a rectangle above your image. Then apply:

- Black fill at 70% opacity
- Background blur at about 25px

[image]